# Use Anaconda installed pip

Tags: python, pip

I have

```
python --version
Python 3.6.9 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

but

```
pip3 --version
pip 19.2.2 from /home/ss/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)
pip --version
pip 19.2.2 from /home/ss/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

I installed pip for anaconda as

```
conda install -c anaconda pip
```

But it did not change the pip path, it is still 3.5 sys path.

How do I use pip installed in anaconda python dir for python 3.6.9?

Comment: Use `python -m pip --version`

Comment: @C.Nivs reply in the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `python -m pip <operation>`

The reason you want to use `python -m <module>` is that `pip` might not necessarily refer to the python installation you are referring to. Even if you have run `activate /some/env`, that still doesn't guarantee that the `pip` binary will be the one used.

For instance, the `$PATH` environment variable might have the python paths appended rather than prepended, so `pip` might live in `/usr/local/bin` which will be searched first, giving the wrong `pip`.

However, you *know* which python you want to use, and by using the `-m` flag, you explicitly tie that module to the python version specified by `python`